# Tkinter - NameError: Name Is Not Defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a simple addition and subtraction game in Tkinter.

```
import random
import Tkinter as tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("250x150")
window.title("Maths Game Login")
window.iconbitmap("mathsgame_1_16x16.icns")
window.configure(background="firebrick")
username = ""
password = ""


def login():
    if entusername.get() == username and entpassword.get() == password:
            game_window = tkinter.Toplevel(window)
            game_window.title("Maths Game")
            game_window.configure(background="firebrick")
            game_window.geometry("500x250")
            number1 = random.randint(0, 9)
            number2 = random.randint(0, 9)
            addorsubtract = random.randint(1,2)
            lblno1 = tkinter.Label(game_window, text="{0}".format(number1), bg="firebrick", fg="yellow", font=("Courier", 100))
            lblno1.place(x=50, y=60)
            lblno2 = tkinter.Label(game_window, text="{0}".format(number2), bg="firebrick", fg="yellow", font=("Courier", 100))
            lblno2.place(x=200, y=60)
            if addorsubtract == 1:
                additionsign = tkinter.Label(game_window, text="+", bg="firebrick", fg="yellow", font=("Courier", 100))
                additionsign.place(x=125, y=60)
            elif addorsubtract == 2:
                subtractsign = tkinter.Label(game_window, text="-", bg="firebrick", fg="yellow", font=("Courier", 100))
                subtractsign.place(x=125, y=60)
            equalssign = tkinter.Label(game_window, text="=", bg="firebrick", fg="yellow", font=("Courier", 100))
            equalssign.place(x=275, y=60)
            entanswer = tkinter.Entry(game_window, bg="yellow", fg="firebrick", width=2, font=("Courier", 100))
            entanswer.place(x=350, y=60)
            if addorsubtract == 1:
                global sum1
                sum1 = int(number1) + int(number2)
                print("{0}".format(sum1))
            elif addorsubtract == 2:
                global sum2
                sum2 = int(number1) - int(number2)
                print("{0}".format(sum2))

            def submitanswer():
                if int(entanswer.get()) == int(sum2) or int(entanswer.get()) == int(sum1):
                    print("Correct")
                else
                    print("Try Again")
            submitbtn = tkinter.Button(game_window, text="Check Answer", highlightbackground="firebrick", cursor="gumby", command=submitanswer)
            submitbtn.place(x=360, y=200)

    else:
        exit()


lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Hatim's Maths Game", bg="firebrick", fg="yellow", font=('Courier', 18))
lbl.pack()
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username:", bg="firebrick", fg="yellow")
lbl.pack()
entusername = tkinter.Entry(window)
entusername.pack()
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password:", bg="firebrick", fg="yellow" )
lbl.pack()
entpassword = tkinter.Entry(window, show="*")
entpassword.pack()
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", highlightbackground="firebrick", command=login, cursor="gumby")
btn.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

I am having an issue as when running the program, if I press `submitbtn`, I am told that there is a `NameError: global name 'sum2' is not defined`. I'm not sure if believe that the issue lies in the variables `sum1` and `sum2` however any changes I have tried to make have been ineffective
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would start the login function by declaring all the globals that you want to use inside the function, even before the conditional `if entusername.get() == username ...`

Comment: The code above returns a different error, please _verify_ the code.

Comment: put a print statement everywhere  you set `sum2`, and print statements everywhere you _use_ `sum2`.  You will almost certainly find that you are using it before you are setting it.